# How to use inline-block and position sticky

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100%
}

.header,
.footer {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100vw;
  /* This line is creating problem when the table overflows horizontally */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="table"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

The table may overflow vertically and horizontally and may shrink. The header and the footer will stick to the left of the page.
The problem is that when the page overflows horizontally, it's taking the max-width of 100vw. This is actually adding additional
12px to that of the body width. I guess that 12px is the width of the scroll bar.
I would like to keep the width of the header and footer as same as that of body width always. Is that possible?

Comment: Include the code for this, so that I can run it and fix your problem

Comment: The problem is sometimes, the browser horizontal bar doesn't disappear fully. The scrollbar is visible, but without the bar :) Its happening very randomly. When I resize the browser, the scroll bar disappears as expected. Looks like painting issue, don't know

Comment: We need you to show us some code

Comment: Thank you for asking. I just modified the question and added sample code

Comment: @Ram did you run your snippet? I can't see anything.

Answer (score -3):

Just remove it.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100%
}

.header,
.footer {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.table {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">bla bla bla</div>
  <div class="table">bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</div>
  <div class="footer">bla bla bla</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. The reason I'm giving 100vw for header and footer is that, I want both of them to remain in view port width. But the table alone is allowed to scroll horizontally. So table's width can be much larger than view port width. The main problem for me is that, based on my current logic, when the table expands horizontally, it's setting a width equal to 100vw for header and footer. This 100vw is the width that includes the scroll bar. The moment the table shrinks (meaning table width less than 100vw), it's putting up a horizontal scroll bar for no reason.

Comment: It is a known bug @Ram , [4th known bug](https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) . Just remove it or use a value lesser than 100...

Comment: I have tried some workaround for this. calc(100vw - 12px). But this leaves a 12px white space when the page doesn't have the scroll bar. I have  seen body width is always seem to be accurate. When page puts up scroll bar body width is automatically subtracting the 12px. I'm not able to set the body with to the header and footer. It's because it's parent container width needs to be bigger enough for sticky left to work  The javascript way of tracking  the body width like resize event also doesn't seem to be reliable. It's doesn't track dom changes :)